# How can turn my validate function into a ajax method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", mouseOver1);

function mouseOver1(){

   document.getElementById("button1").style.color = "red";

}


document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", mouseOver); 


    function mouseOver(){ 

      document.getElementById("button2").style.color = "purple";
   }



$("#button1").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
}); 

$("#button2").hover(function() {
    $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
});

$(document).ready(function() {

   $(".login").validate({
      rules: {
       existingUsername: {
       required: true, 
       minlength: 10
     },
       existingPassword:{
       required: true, 
       minlength: 10 
      },
        
       messages: {
          existingUsername: {
           required: "You must enter a valid existing user account", 
           minlength: "Your username must be at least 10 characters long"
          }, 
           existingPassword: {
           required: "You must enter a valid password associated with an account", 
           minlength: "Your username must be at least 10 characters long"
         }
```

```css
intro h1 {
  font-family: 'Cambria';
  font-size: 16pt;
  font: bold;
  text-align: left;
}

.intro p {
  font-family: 'Calibri';
  font: italic;
  font-size: 12pt;
  padding: 0px 690px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left;
}

.content {
  border: 2px solid;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#para1 {
  padding: 0px 1050px 0px 20px;
}

#para2 {
  padding: 0px 1099px 0px 20px;
}

.username-label,
.password-label {
 margin: 10px 0px 0px 300px;
 position: relative; 
 top: -70px; 
}

.existing1-username-input-textbox, 
.existing2-password-input-textbox
{
    top: -70px; 
     position: relative; 
      
}

#button1{ 
     background-color: #add8e6;
     margin-left: 390px; 
     position: relative; 
     top: -50px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius:10px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; 
}

#button2{
  background-color: #add8e6;
  margin-left: -200px; 
  position: relative; 
  top: -30px; 
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px; 

}


.Username-label1, 
.Password-label2,           
.Email-label3, 
.Repeat-Email-label4 
{
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 300px;
  position: relative; 
  top: -70px; 
}
.username-new-input-textbox, 
.password-new-input-textbox, 
.email-new-input-textbox, 
.reenter-new-input-textbox{ 
  position: relative;
   top: -70px;
  margin-left: 20px; 

} 

span{
  
 color: red; 
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link href="Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Project</title>

</head>

<body>


<div class="container">
  <div class="intro">

    <h1>Welcome to Cuyahoga Community College Student Services Online</h1>

    <p>Cuyahoga Community College recognizes students' rights to access personal and academic records in accordance with the Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act of 1974 (FERPA) as amended by Public Law 93-568.</p>
  </div>
  <br/>

  <div class="content">
    <div class="row top">
      <p id="para1">Already have an account with us? Returning users may log in by entering their site username and password. </p>
      <div class="login">
        <label class="username-label" for="existingUsername">Username</label> 
         <input class="existingUsername" type="text" value=""> 
         <span id="username_error1">*</span><br>

        <label class="password-label" for="existingPassword">Password</label>
        <input class="existingPassword" type="password" value="">
        <span id="password_error2">*</span><br>
        <button id="button1">Log in</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="row bottom">
      <p id="para2">New users, please create a new account by providing us with some basic information.</p>

      <div class= "new_customers_info">

        <label class="Username-label1" for="newUsername">Username</label>
        <input class="newUsername" type="text" value="">
         <br/><br/>

        <label class="Password-label2" for="newPassword">Password</label>
        <input class="newPassword" type="password" value="">
         <br/><br/>

        <label class="Email-label3" for="newEmail">Email Address</label>
         <input class="newEmail" type="email" value="" >
          <br/><br/>

        <label class="Repeat-Email-label4" for="repeatEmail">Repeat Email Address</label>
         <input class="repeatEmail" type="email" value="">

        <button id="button2">Create Account</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
   <br/>
  <footer>Cuyahoga Community College</footer>
  <footer>700 Carnegie Avenue, Cleveland, Ohio, 44115</footer>
</div>
    <script src="Home.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I validate each of (upper textboxes) using AJAX to see if the username and password is correct and if they are not correct, display the error messages in red below each respective textbox. Here is my code. Any suggestions would be help. I know I could use the $.ajax() method, but I don't know how I can translate my current validate function into the sensible ajax method.

Comment: @charlietfl the ajax form validation below doesn't show how to do validate through the ajax method.

Comment: Lots of them do ... look for a plugin/script that is well documented and has features you want

Comment: @ charlietfl How can I validate without showing the correct username and password?

Comment: @ charlietfl is it even possible to do what I am asking to do with my validate function?

Comment: @charlietfl You mean there are already preloaded scripts on the internet I can use to handle input textboxes validation?

Comment: @ charlietfl But I want to learn how to do with the ajax method. Do you think you could help me?

Comment: I just noticed you are already using `validate()` plugin... read docs...it has a `remote` option that uses ajax interally

Comment: @ charlietfl  Would the code I posted below be a form of how ajax works internally.

Comment: @ charlietfl  And so technically just because I don't write an ajax method doesn't mean that it's not ajax , right?

Comment: @charlietfl -How can I use this to make sure that what the person puts into the two textboxes above are the correct username and password without me having to reveal what the username and password is in validate function? For example, equalTo:"Mic32" (which could be username) could be part of this validate function.

Comment: you use remote option to send to server and validate there. Read validate docs and other posts here regarding using remote option

Comment: @ charlietfl I found out from someone else I don't have to use ajax method to validate my input textboxes. I updated my code to show what Iam currently struggling with. Using the jquery validation plug in instead, but I don't know why JS bin developer tool gets saying something is wrong. Take a look at new code above.

Answer (score 0):

```html
$(".selector").validate({
   rules: yourRules,
   messages: {
     username: {
       remote: "Username already exists"
     }
   }
})

// This is cited from Stack Overflow. Would this how Ajax work internally?  

*/http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6772154/using-the-jquery- validate-plugin-with-the-remote-option?rq=1 /*
```